# I try to make an animation with Java.Swing but the frame rate is very low and unconstant

Tags: java, swing, animation, physics

I would like to simulate physic with entities that interacts with each other in jave. I would like to animate the simulation. I read a tutorial on how to make animation with Java.Swing Everything works fine but the frame rate of the simulation is to low even if I don't simulate many things. Even if my laptop in not the more powerful one, it's stills capable of calculate this simulation normally.

Here is the entities that I simule

```
public class Point {

    private int x; 
    private int y;
    private int[] speed = new int[2]; 

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int[] get_position() {
        return new int[]{this.x, this.y};
    }

    public int[] get_speed() {
        return this.speed;
    }

    public void modify_position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void modify_speed(int speed_x, int speed_y) {
        this.speed[0] = speed_x;
        this.speed[1] = speed_y;
    }

    public void add_position(int speed_x, int speed_y) {
        this.x += speed_x;
        this.y += speed_y;
    }
}
```

Here we have the JPanel code

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimulationPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public ArrayList<Point> listPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

    private int width = 1000;
    private int height = 1000;

    public SimulationPanel() {
        
        Point p1 = new Point(10, 10);
        Point p2 = new Point(20, 20);
        Point p3 = new Point(30, 30);

        p1.modify_speed(5, 1);
        p2.modify_speed(1, 5);
        p3.modify_speed(5, 5);

        listPoints.add(p1);
        listPoints.add(p2);
        listPoints.add(p3);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        Timer timer = new Timer(40, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof Timer) {
            for (Point p : listPoints) {
                p.add_position(p.get_speed()[0], p.get_speed()[1]);
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(java.awt.Color.RED);        
        for (Point p : listPoints) {
            g2.fillOval(p.get_position()[0], p.get_position()[1], 10, 10);
        }
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

and finaly the JFrame file

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimulationFrame {

    public SimulationFrame() {
        JFrame simulationFrame = new JFrame();
        simulationFrame.setContentPane(new SimulationPanel());
        simulationFrame.pack();
        simulationFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
        simulationFrame.setVisible(true);
        simulationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimulationFrame();
    }
}
```

I tried to optimize my code to increase the frame rate level but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I made a few minor changes to your code.

1. I called the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method to start the application.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I moved the `simulationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` to its proper location.  The `JFrame` methods must be called in a specific order.
3. I decreased the speed of the points.  You should only move pixels or fractions of a pixel in a time period if you want smooth motion.  To make up for the slower speed, I decreased the Swing `Timer` time.  The minimum Swing `Timer` time is 5 milliseconds.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made your additional classes inner classes so I could compile, run, and post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SimulationFrame {

    public SimulationFrame() {
        JFrame simulationFrame = new JFrame();
        simulationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        simulationFrame.setContentPane(new SimulationPanel());
        simulationFrame.pack();
        simulationFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
        simulationFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SimulationFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public class SimulationPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ArrayList<Point> listPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

        private int width = 1000;
        private int height = 1000;

        public SimulationPanel() {

            Point p1 = new Point(10, 10);
            Point p2 = new Point(20, 20);
            Point p3 = new Point(30, 30);

            p1.modify_speed(2, 1);
            p2.modify_speed(1, 2);
            p3.modify_speed(2, 2);

            listPoints.add(p1);
            listPoints.add(p2);
            listPoints.add(p3);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
            Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
            timer.start();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof Timer) {
                for (Point p : listPoints) {
                    p.add_position(p.get_speed()[0], p.get_speed()[1]);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setColor(java.awt.Color.RED);
            for (Point p : listPoints) {
                g2.fillOval(p.get_position()[0], p.get_position()[1], 10, 10);
            }
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class Point {

        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int[] speed = new int[2];

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int[] get_position() {
            return new int[] { this.x, this.y };
        }

        public int[] get_speed() {
            return this.speed;
        }

        public void modify_position(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void modify_speed(int speed_x, int speed_y) {
            this.speed[0] = speed_x;
            this.speed[1] = speed_y;
        }

        public void add_position(int speed_x, int speed_y) {
            this.x += speed_x;
            this.y += speed_y;
        }
    }
}
```